# SceneBuilder crashed upon startup

Tags: ubuntu, javafx, scenebuilder, ubuntu-17.04

I performed the installation of [SceneBuilder 8.3.0](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 with Java Hotspot 1.8.0_131 installed, but when trying to start it, an error occurs, making it impossible to initialize. I've already tried installing Oracle's SceneBuilder 2.0, but the same error occurs.

[image: Error Part 1]
[image: Error Part 2]
[image: Error Part 3]
[image: Error Part 4]

Do you know what that can be and how I can solve it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'm having this problem too, since yesterday, I'm using JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 from Oracle and Ubuntu 16.04 OS, at initialization just show the icon in launcher and after it closes itself, and JDK is the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that calling directly the SceneBuilder jar "dist.jar"  with the java Hotspot, the application launches smoothly ("java - jar /opt/SceneBuilder/app/dist.jar"). So one way to solve this problem palliatively is to edit the file "/usr/share/applications/SceneBuilder.desktop" and change the line:

```
Exec=/opt/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder
```

for:

```
Exec=java -jar /opt/SceneBuilder/app/dist.jar
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ricardo! The palliative worked perfectly and SceneBuilder initializes without errors! Thanks!!!