# Gluon scenebuilder is not launching ubuntu

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

On ubuntu I installed scene builder it won't launch. Also didn't give any type of exception. Icon blinks for few seconds and then stops.

Comment: can you try running it from terminal and see if there is any output?

Comment: how to run it from the terminal. I write "scenebuilder" on terminal but the output is that "command not found".

Comment: I believe it is installed under `/opt/SceneBuilder` by default, so you should try `/opt/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder`

Comment: "/opt/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder" after running this command it said "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: When I downloaded it, I download it into segments because it auto failed  2 times. what do you say? Is it's because of a corrupt file or something else.

Comment: I installed the deb package on my ubuntu 16.04 a while ago and it worked until it won't start today (I haven't used it for a week or so).  I removed and reinstalled the deb package, same problem.  I first thought was because I changed jdk from 1.8.0_60 to 1.8.0_131.  So I rolled back to _60.  Same problem.  Only way I can get it to work is to download the scenebuilder-all-8.3.0-all.jar and run it with "java -jar scenebuilder-all-8.3.0-all.jar".  Very strange problem.

Comment: Also, I have JavaFXSceneBuilder 2.0 installed long time ago and it worked before.  But it also gives core dump today.

Comment: Can you check if the Linux kernel has been recently updated? Check this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927746/eclipse-crashes-with-linux-kernel-4-4-0-81-generic/927824), there is a possible workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I have the same issue here. I run scene builder alongside with intelliJ IDE on my laptop(elementary os loki). I tried to googling around and finally found a workaround from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659100/scenebuilder-crashed-upon-startup). May it helps you!

p.s.: I still can't open it directly from intelliJ, so I open the scene builder separately.

Comment: put two lines into a script and make it executable.  Point the path from IDE to the script.  It will work.  Note there should be a new line after #!/bin/sh, the comment won't let me have the new line, sorry.

Comment: #!/bin/sh
java -jar /opt/SceneBuilder/app/dist.jar $*

Answer (score 3):

[@José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%c3%a9-pereda) pointed out that the problem could be a bug in kernel. He linked [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927746/eclipse-crashes-with-linux-kernel-4-4-0-81-generic/927824) that gives workaround to this problem.

> export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xss1280k