# JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 Segmentation Fault

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

JavaFX was working, but strangely, it throws `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)` now.

I don't know where the logs are kept, so I have launcher app/SceneBuilderApp.jar, just in case:

```
Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load file:/opt/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0/app/SceneBuilderApp.jar!/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/DocumentWindow.fxml
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractFxmlWindowController.makeRoot(AbstractFxmlWindowController.java:114)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractWindowController.getRoot(AbstractWindowController.java:91)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractWindowController.getScene(AbstractWindowController.java:111)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractWindowController.getStage(AbstractWindowController.java:134)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.openWindow(DocumentWindowController.java:1088)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleLaunch(SceneBuilderApp.java:418)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStartGeneric(AppPlatform.java:139)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStart(AppPlatform.java:106)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.start(SceneBuilderApp.java:371)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load file:/opt/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0/app/SceneBuilderApp.jar!/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/info/InfoPanel.fxml
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractFxmlPanelController.makePanel(AbstractFxmlPanelController.java:93)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractPanelController.getPanelRoot(AbstractPanelController.java:130)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.controllerDidLoadFxml(DocumentWindowController.java:985)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractFxmlWindowController.makeRoot(AbstractFxmlWindowController.java:110)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load file:/opt/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0/app/SceneBuilderKit.jar!/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/editor/panel/inspector/editors/StringAutoSuggestEditor.fxml
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.EditorUtils.loadFxml(EditorUtils.java:483)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.EditorUtils.loadFxml(EditorUtils.java:463)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.AutoSuggestEditor.preInit(AutoSuggestEditor.java:124)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.AutoSuggestEditor.<init>(AutoSuggestEditor.java:118)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.AutoSuggestEditor.<init>(AutoSuggestEditor.java:103)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.ControllerClassEditor.<init>(ControllerClassEditor.java:51)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.info.InfoPanelController.performInitialization(InfoPanelController.java:186)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.info.InfoPanelController.controllerDidLoadFxml(InfoPanelController.java:173)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractFxmlPanelController.makePanel(AbstractFxmlPanelController.java:89)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
    file:/opt/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0/app/SceneBuilderKit.jar!/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/editor/panel/inspector/editors/StringAutoSuggestEditor.fxml

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.EditorUtils.loadFxml(EditorUtils.java:481)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.AutoSuggestEditor.initialize(AutoSuggestEditor.java:142)
        ... 41 more
    Exception running application com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp
```

### Environment

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)

Comment: Scene Builder 2.0 is *very* old. Have you tried a [more recent version](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download)?

Comment: Let me grab it. I didn't know there was newer version of it. Thanks.

Comment: Just in case, I'm waiting for an answer. Maybe, it can help a Googler.

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674181/gluon-scenebuilder-is-not-launching-ubuntu). But your exception doesn't relate to a segmentation fault?

Comment: It relates to a segmentation fault. At least, this is what bash dumps. Let me see that thread, too. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SceneBuilder crashed upon startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659100/scenebuilder-crashed-upon-startup)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you did. 
As in the thread already mentioned this seems to be a kernel bug. Updating Ubuntu as usually + running dist-upgrade did the trick for me.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301484/how-do-i-update-ubuntu-manually) for information what dist-upgrade does.