# Scene Builder crashes Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: scenebuilder

I'm using Eclipse Neon with Scene Builder and cannot open fxml files since yesterday. I didn't commit any changes to my station.
When I'm trying to open an existing fxml file nothing happens.

I tried also to run the Scene Builder from the terminal but then I got segmentation fault error.

I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44683216/4193208), but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved the problem by returning to an old version of the Ubuntu generic kernel.